# SQL Compact to SQL Server (shared hosting) & table prefixes

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

Sorry if this has been asked before, I've been searching but not really finding my answer.

I have a blog that I developed (MVC 4, EF code first) and am using SQL Compact locally. Now I want to move to my hosting provider and when I script out the DB schema (using sql server compact toolbox) and run it against the SQL server - it prepends all my tables with my username. This apparently is causing my application to error out that it can't find tables such as 'dbo.Posts' because they're all prefaced with my username.

To clarify the error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Posts'.

Connection string is correct. I can manage the db from SQL Management Studio.

Here's a screen shot of my local sql compact db:

[image: LocalDB]

Here's what my database looks like after migrating on the SQL server:

[image]

See the prefix?

And if you care here's the stack trace:
    Stack Trace:

```
Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Posts'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2073486
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064444
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +86
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +311
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +443

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +479
System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +736
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +149
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +40
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +23
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
ASP._Page_Views_posts_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\PData\Bare Blog Blog Engine\Web\BareBlogAdmin\BareBlogAdmin\Views\Posts\Index.cshtml:48
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +65
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +255
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +19
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +92
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +126
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +9
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

If I run LinqPad against my host's database, it works as expected, but not my MVC app using DBContext.

Ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "freak"? Can you show the exception? Check your connection string and whether you can access the database with the given user.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT!!!

I logged in to the remote database via SQL management and changed the default schema for my User to "dbo". I then deleted my old tables and re-migrated... everything came up as "dbo.table-name". Ran my app - IT WORKS!

Ugh what a pain. As you can tell... I'm no DBA. ;)